# How to get 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget

I just created an MVC5 project and added several packages from nuget, but then when I compiled the project, i got this error.  It seems one of the packages really depends on system.web.http version 5.2.3.0, which i couldn't find anywhere. I just wonder how to get the latest version of system.web.http ?

```
Error   2   Assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   d:\Backup 2014-12-25\Website-Projects\www.ptsol.com.au\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll
```

Answer (score 125):

In Package Manager Console

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core -version 5.2.3`

Comment: I did but still giving me the same error <br/><pre>PM> install-package microsoft.aspnet.webapi.core -version 5.2.3
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 5.2.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 6.0.4)'.
'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3' already installed.
www.ptsol.com.au already has a reference to 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3'.</pre>

Comment: @JohnHadikusumo do this for *all* of your projects.  It appears you have a dependent project with an older version.

Comment: Yes, this will work.  Carefully read your Web.config and your packages.config both before and after you run this command and you'll see what changed.

Comment: Solved my problem.

Comment: I had to use `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 5.2.7` instead (.Client instead of .Core). I had .Core 5.2.7 already, but I was still getting the error. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/

Answer (score 19):

One way to fix it is by modifying the assembly redirect in the web.config file.

Modify the following:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

to

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

So the oldVersion attribute should change from "...-4.0.0.0" to "...-5.2.3.0".

Comment: This worked for me. We had the `bindingRedirect` setup as `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />` but changed it to use `4.0.0.0`. Still doesn't makes sense to me, because should be using the NuGet package DLL and not the GAC version, but hey, it worked... so thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I did `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core -version 5.2.3` but it still did not work.  Then looked in my project bin folder and saw that it still had the old System.Web.Mvc file.

So I manually copied the newer file from the package to the bin folder. Then I was up and running again.

Answer (score 7):

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core -version 5.2.3

Then in the project Add Reference -> Browse. Push the browse button and go to the 
 C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ProjectName\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45 and add the needed .dll file

Answer (score 7):

The packages you installed introduced dependencies to version 5.2.3.0 dll's as user Bracher showed above. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors is an example package. The path I take is to **update the MVC project proir** to any package installs:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.mvc

Answer (score 4):

Uninstalling and re-installing the NuGet package worked for me.

1. Remove any old reference from the project.

Execute this in the Package Manager Console:

2. `UnInstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core -version 5.2.3`
3. `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core -version 5.2.3`

Comment: Just this one solved my problem. I've done so much and win-action was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

install this in your nuget package manager

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost -Version 5.2.7
```

and paste

using System.Web.Http;

This should work