# Understand System.Web.Mvc, Version =5.2.3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've had this error now three times.  Working on a web api project over last few days.   I'm not sure what or why this is happening and I want to fix the error.

I've looked at a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604325/how-to-get-system-web-http-version-5-2-3-0).  I also tried to install in the package manager: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors.ko -Version 5.0.0`

When doing that install an error of:  "already referencing a new version of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" is thrown and it rolls back the install.

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors.ko 5.0.0 requires

**Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors (= 5.0.0)**

Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors 5.0.0 requires

**Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (>= 5.2.3 && < 5.3.0) and Microsoft.AspNet.Cors (>= 5.2.3)**

be sure, that all dependencies (versions of packages) are right in your project

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors.ko/5.0.0

> Dependencies
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors (= 5.0.0)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors/

> Dependencies
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (>= 5.2.3 && < 5.3.0)
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Cors (>= 5.2.3)