# Installing Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi makes an existing controller's action route invalid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have two projects - one MVC and other Web Api. Both have one controller with the same name (DealsController).

It is working fine since we have specific route mentioned in all actions for Web Api deals controller.

Web api deals controller looks like:

```
public class DealsController : ApiController
{
        [Route("api/advantage/getDeals/")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetDeals([FromUri] CompanyName.Entity.Deals.Filters filter)
        {

        }
}
```

Both are working fine till the time i install package - Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.
Once i am installing this package in my project that has web api, this action starts giving me error.

```
{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/api/advantage/getDeals/?cityId=10&sc=0&so=1&pn=1'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'advantage'."
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled Attribute Routing in your web api?

Comment: Yes. It is working fine with other Web api controllers. They are using route too. Issue is with this controller since its duplicate

Comment: What's your MVC controller look like? Couldn't reproduce the problem here.. Also, you installed Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi in the Web api project, correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802824/unable-to-hit-duplicate-controller-route-after-installing-fluentvalidation-webap

This is another question i posted for same problem. This has definition of mvc controller.

Comment: It seems confusing. You have 1 project for both MVC and Web api? Or each of them are different projects in the same solution?

Comment: I have different projects in the same solution.