# WebAPI call not working in ASP.NET MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

Here my Web API call working fine in Browser ,

[image]

I want to make the front end using MVC So I just create mvc 5 application business logic like below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using ProductApp.Core.Entities;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace ProductApp.MVC.Models
{
    public class ProductClient
    {
        private string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:11661/api/Products";

        public IEnumerable<Product> findAll()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("product").Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>().Result;
                return null;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

then the view

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    // GET: Product
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ProductClient pc = new ProductClient();
        ViewBag.listproducts = pc.findAll(); 
        return View();
    }
}
```

But Once I Compile this getting this kind error

[image]

Something like

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting,
>   Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference.

then I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604325/how-to-get-system-web-http-version-5-2-3-0)  which is not working , How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: *Remove all code references to `System.Net.*` and run `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` Clean and rebuild your project*

Comment: You are mixing upp C# MVC controller with Web API ApiController. They are different. Read this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: @MarcusH I'm very new to this technology , basically what I did was GET the WEB API URL then handle it on `ProductClient` class under `findall` method , then created MVC controller and Create that  `ProductClient` object invoke `findall` method , is it wrong please advise

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` reference to your solution