# Assembly, C #, Update

Tags: c#, reference, .net-assembly

I have this dummy problem, can you help me with it? How to update the reference version. There is no such version in my lists of References.[image]

Comment: is this from a Nuget?

Comment: Also, what version of .Net is your application running? as  from the image I think this is a .Net 4.x.x. library youre trying to reference

Comment: Whether the System.Web.Http version 4.0.0.0 is referred in your project?

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604325/how-to-get-system-web-http-version-5-2-3-0

Answer (score 0):

The optimum DLL requires the System.Web.Http version 4.0.0.0. But in your project you referred the higher version of System.Web.Http which is 5.2.3.0 . So confirm the same in your project and remove the higher version assembly version and attach the required version 4.0.0.0